# Android app removed from Google Play store due to no prominent disclosure

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

My app is showing the prominent disclosure in my view and also has a switch to agree with the privacy policy. But the app still gets removed by Google over and over again.
Response from Google is just:

> Your app is uploading users' contact list information without a
> prominent disclosure. Prior to the collection and transmission, it
> must prominently highlight how the user data will be used, describe
> the type of data being collected and have the user provide affirmative
> consent for such use.

We are not even accessing the contact list in any way.

[image]

Can someone please help with this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Stripe sdk, make sure you update to a version 14.4 or greater, since older versions are non-compliant.